# Table type parameter in a stored procedure cause operand type clash error

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, user-defined-types

I want to give an array of identifiers as argument to a stored procedure.

The stored procedure looks like :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchPerson]
    @personType INT = NULL,
    @city NVARCHAR(64) = NULL,
    @siteIds IntegerList READONLY,
    -- some other params...
AS
    SELECT
        -- some fields...
    FROM dbo.PersonView AS pv
    WHERE
    (
        (@personType IS NULL OR pv.PersonType = @personType) AND
        (@city IS NULL OR pv.City LIKE '%' + @city + '%') AND
        (pv.SiteId in (SELECT si.Value FROM @siteIds AS si)) AND
        -- some other params filter...
    )
```

The user table type looks like :

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntegerList] AS TABLE(
    [Value] [int] NULL
)
```

When I call the stored procedure from a script in SSMS (I originally have the same problem calling it from .NET code) :

```
DECLARE @siteIds AS IntegerList,
@personType AS INT = 1
INSERT INTO @siteIds VALUES (1)
EXEC [dbo].[SearchPerson] @personType, @siteIds
```

I got the error :

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with IntegerList

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the answer : it was the order of the table type parameter that caused the error !

**The table type parameter must be the first in the stored procedure parameters AND ALSO in the arguments passed to the stored procedure call !**

The stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchPerson]
    @siteIds IntegerList READONLY, -- THIS PARAMETER HAS TO BE THE FIRST !
    @personType INT = NULL,
    @city NVARCHAR(64) = NULL,
    -- some other params...
AS
    SELECT
        -- some fields...
    FROM dbo.PersonView AS pv
    WHERE
    (
        (@personType IS NULL OR pv.PersonType = @personType) AND
        (@city IS NULL OR pv.City LIKE '%' + @city + '%') AND
        (pv.SiteId in (SELECT si.Value FROM @siteIds AS si)) AND
        -- some other params filter...
    )
```

And the call :

```
DECLARE @siteIds AS IntegerList,
@personType AS INT = 1
INSERT INTO @siteIds VALUES (1)
EXEC [dbo].[SearchPerson] @siteIds, @personType -- PUT @siteIds FIRST !
```

A sql server bug or am I missing something ?

Comment: Either they fixed this in 2008R2 or the way the table type is defined affects its use. I effectively had the same user table type but the Value column was not nullable and had a PK constraint on it. In my SP the table parameter had other parameters both before and after it.

Comment: Thanks for this - although calling the stored procedure directly with a tabled valued parameter not first worked in direct SQL (Management studio), I was having problems when calling it from .Net Code (Entity Framework 5 - `System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery` ) re-arranging the table-valued parms first in the stored proc + calling code fixed it!

Comment: @JamesS : I had the problem when calling it from .NET code too.

Answer (score 3):

```
  DECLARE @ErrMsg varchar(1000)
  DECLARE @ServiceDates ServiceDatesType

  INSERT @ServiceDates (indexId,unitOfDay,dayOfMonth,dateOfMonth)
  VALUES 
  (0,1,11,'9/11/2016 12:00:00 AM'),
  (1,1,12,'9/12/2016 12:00:00 AM'),
  (2,1,13,'9/13/2016 12:00:00 AM')   

EXEC [usp_SaveValidate] 427,4,12,9,2016,@ErrMsg output,@ServiceDates  
PRINT @ErrMsg
*/

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SaveValidate] (      
     @EpisodeNo INT 
    ,@ProviderId INT
    ,@ServiceId INT 
    ,@Month INT 
    ,@Year INT          
    ,@ErrorMessage VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT 
    ,@ServiceDates ServiceDatesType ReadOnly
    )
AS
BEGIN
 -- Code Here
END
```

SQL SERVER 2012 - location of table type parameter does not matter, you have to make sure sequence while passing data, you can check above code which is working fine where table type parameter is at the last.